# Datagrid in wpf showing corner in cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf app in which i am showing the log which is mapped to a datagrid. I don't want and border and lines in the data grid. I tried everything but not able to achieve that.
I am also attaching how it looks on the wpf ui. I just want to remove the border corners.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxC9b.png)
Xaml code

```
<DataGrid 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      Height="216"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredEventLogList}"
                      Background="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}"
                      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Width="614"
                      RowHeaderWidth="0"
                      GridLinesVisibility="None"
                      BorderThickness="1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5"
                      BorderBrush="Gray"
                         
                >
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        
                        
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}"
                             Value="Error">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="OrangeRed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}"
                             Value="Warning">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}"
                             Value="Info">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}"
                             Value="Success">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LimeGreen"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Binding="{Binding LogTime}"
                        Header="Time" 
                        Width="Auto"
                        >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Binding="{Binding Log}"
                        Header="Message"
                        Width="*" 
                        >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn
                        Binding="{Binding Level}"
                        Header="Log Type" 
                        Width="100" 
                        >
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PageBackgroundColor}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>-->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a BorderThichness in your cell style set to 5. Have to tryied to set it to 0? You can also set the BorderBrush to Transparent to make them invisible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Neeraj Thanks for your hint but my answer contains only two simple hints. Set the BorderThickness to 0 or set the BorderBrush to Transparent. Both can be testet within seconds. In my opinion there is no need for such a documentation.